# Slide animation, 2 UIViews, SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

**Background:** I created a UIView inside a View Controller. This UIView has 9 images within it, "cannons". I also made a xib file that has the same exact UIView structure.

Problem: How do I make a **vertically down** sliding animation, off the screen, infinitely with these two views?

(In other words, when one view slides all the way off screen, how do I have my second UIView follow it. How to get this process to repeat forever also.)

The UIView inside the ViewController is called "CannonView"
The .xib file is called "SecondCannonView"

If you need more info, just comment below and I'll add it immediately.

Best regards, Jordan

[image]

*Don't mind the blue dot and the yellow dot.*

Comment: I'm not able to understand what do you mean by "How do I make a vertically down sliding animation infinitely with these two views?"

Comment: In other words, when one view slides all the way off screen, how do I have my second UIView follow it. How to get this process to repeat forever also.